# storing bottles

Tags: storage, bottles

Simple question: How do you store a lot of bottles (empty and full) in a small space?

I get a lot of bottles from friends, often arriving to me in 6-packs, and I have some odds and ends (i.e. 500mL, 1L, etc) that really don't fit anywhere.  I've tried using milk crates, but they don't really work because the grid doesn't really let a bottle sit flat.  Has anybody found a relatively inexpensive solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I keep the bottles in 24 bottle cases for my 12oz-ers.  And I keep my 22's in a 12 bottle case that they get shipped in.  You can get these at your local beer store as most beer is shipped in 6 pack holders in a larger box.

I had a bunch of 1L belgian style bottles that I kept in a rubbermaid bin.  But I had to be honest with myself recently and I tossed them out, because I just wasn't ready to use them anytime soon.

So in boxes is a must for stacking, and a bin for oddball sizes. Most importantly is to be honest with yourself whether you'll really use them.  Keep you inventory to a reasonable size.

Comment: I've learned that if you're friendly with the liquor store staff, they'll let you take an extra empty box home.

Answer (score 1):

Wine/champagne cartons are useful for the odd sized ones like the squat 500 mL and 1 L bottles, as they are taller and the spaces are wider than typical beer cartons. I get these at grocery stores that stock wine/champagne.